# php PDO and mysql: how to insert a geo point type?

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation, pdo, geometry

Here's my (simplified) code to insert values into tables:

```
function myInsert($pdo, $sql, $values) {
    $pdo->prepare($sql);
    foreach ($values as $key=>$value) {
        $stmt->bindValue($key, $value);
    }   
}

myInsert(
    $pdo,
    'INSERT INTO mytable (a,b,c) VALUES (:a,:b,:c)',
    array(
        ':a' => 'valuea',
        ':b' => 'valueb',
        ':c' => 'valuec',
    )
);
```

What could be the correct `'valuea'` that could represent a MySQL geo point?

Comment: I'd like to know this too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supposed to follow this format:
`POINT( a.latitude, a.longitude )`

BUT for some reason I had trouble doing that, so I simply reused the `:lat` & `:lng` that I had no trouble putting into my database. I was getting an HY000 (couldn't connect to database) error for some reason when my `$newPosition = "POINT(" . $newlat . ", " . $newlng . ")";` line preceded the connection, but with bit of PDO/SQL I no longer had to bother with a $newPosition at all:

`SET lat = :lat, lng = :lng, position = POINT( :lat, :lng)`

Answer (score 0):

Use

> GeomFromText('POINT(1 1)')

```
$valuea = "$lat $lng";

GeomFromText('POINT($valuea)')", //Example: GeomFromText('POINT(31.95635 35.945843)')
```

and be aware of the table column type it should be type of *point*.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    geo_point point DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
)
```

Comment: Nice try, but failed.

Comment: why failed, please explain

Comment: oh, that's simple. just run it and see

Comment: It's my bad. I wrote the code blindly. Thank you, I'll check and update it.